# R: Load mypackage in vignette

Tags: r, package, devtools

I am building an R package (for the first time) and I generated a package vignette using `devtools::use_vignette("my-vignette")`. Of course I want to use this vignette to demonstrate the use of functions in my package. However when I tried to load my package in the vignette by `library(mypackage)` I got this error message:

Error in library("mypackage") : there is no package called ‘mypackage’

When I was developing my package functions I used `devtools::load_all()` to load everything in my package. In the R console if I directly type `library(mypackage)` I got the same error message, but if I `devtools::load_all()` first and then `library(mypackage)` it works.

I think it shouldn't be a hard problem but I just couldn't find an answer anywhere. If someone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you also installed your package?  `install.packages(pkgs="<path to package file reported by devtools::build>", repos=NULL)`?

Comment: It looks like you didn't *build* (i.e. *install*) the package?! Is that correct? Since you seem to be using RStudio you can use the "Install and Restart" functionality  in RStudio's "Build* section  (might need to run *Check* first if you use Roxygen to crate Rd and NAMESPACE files) Alternatively to RStudios "Install and Restart" button you could also use the code mentioned in the comment above or devtool `devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE, upgrade = upgrade)`

Comment: @dario I think you're quite right in your meaning, but for future reference, in the context of R packages, *build* and *install* mean two very different things. Building an R package is done via `R CMD build` (even if you're using `devtools` to do so, that's what they use in the end) and it takes a raw source directory and *prepares* it for installing (including zipping it up in a tarball). Installing is done via `R CMD INSTALL` (again, even if you're using `devtools` or the base `install.packages()`, they just call it), and is what actually installs the package for use.